# I want to remove a bar on NavigationView layout

Tags: java, android, navigationview

I create a NavigationView ,it success.
but it has a bit bug.
I hope I can remove this green and gray bar.(when I create NavigationView,it would appear...
I dont know how to do it.
[image]
this is my code:

xml:

```
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_miaoli_menu"
        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />   
</group>
</menu>
```

nav.java

```
 Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
     navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    navigationView.bringToFront();
```

anyone can help me?
thank in advance.

Comment: I think you are using CoordinatorLayout. If it then show full layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add layout_behavior for root child of coordinate layout in your layout.

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove **app:menu="@menu/activity_miaoli_menu"** this line and Make custom navigation drawer like below-given code, make a layout for each item

```
  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/layout_home"
                            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_48dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/nav_home"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/setting_icon"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/setting_icon"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_double"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_normal"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:clickable="false"
                                android:focusable="false"
                                android:tint="@color/color_f85200"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nav_home"
                                android:text="@string/title_activity_home"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:clickable="false"
                                android:focusable="false"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/sarabun_medium"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_double"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:textColor="@color/DrawerTextColor"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
               </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It's just an alternative approach for creating navigation menu